# mouse listener for array of JPanels

Tags: java, swing

I have got an array of JPanels which themselves contain ImageIcons, I have added this array JPanels to a single JPanel (as I'm using a Scroll Pane). While adding these JPanels I added a mouse listener to each of them, my question is, is it possible to write a single Event handler that can use e.getSource() or other such method where I can extract the JPanel and such the ImageIcon from which one was clicked.

This may sound complicated as I cannot explain my situation very well, but below are some relevant snippets of code I have so far.

```
imageArray=new BufferedImage[256];
imageLabelArray = new JLabel[256];
```

...

```
imageArray[i] = volume.getSlice(image, face, i);//this returns an image
scaledImage = imageArray[i].getScaledInstance(25,25,
                    Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
imageLabelArray[i] = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(scaledImage));
imageLabelArray[i].addMouseListener(this);
```

...

```
for(int i=0;i<255;i++){
    panel.add(imageLabelArray[i]);
}
```

...

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO extract image data
    dispose();
}
```

I can answer any questions that could clear up the problem itself and i will be editing the question to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a class which extends from `JPanel` which has a getter (and probably a setter) which allows you to manage the image.  The rest of the answer then becomes yes.

Simply cast the `MouseEvent#getComponent` result to your "panel" type and you then have access to the functionality to get/set the image

Comment: Didn't even think of writing another class to extend, just implemented this and it worked! Thanks!